# How can I only schedule local notifications once in a day?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I currently have local notifications working on an application but they're working in the viewDidLoad method. That means that every time that the application launches, local notifications are being scheduled which is redundant.

So how can I only have local notifications only being scheduled once per day?

For a little extra detail, I have three local notifications being scheduled every day at 8am, 1pm and 8pm but they're being scheduled every time the app launches.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can check what notifications are scheduled using `[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications`. This returns an NSArray of UILocalNotifications, which you can then use in viewDidLoad to do the necessary checks.

Comment: Also, you should only need to set them once if you specify the `repeatInterval` property of the notification. `notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit` in addition to the `fireDate`

Comment: This would only work if the notification didn't change. I don't know if it does or not, but if it doesn't, the repeatInterval is a very good option.

Comment: Agreed - though it sounded like they were constant ("being scheduled every day at 8am, 1pm and 8pm") but who knows.